# How can i apply multiple filters and multiple value in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have 2 values, I want to filter those values ​​in my data. How can I do it?

I want to filter the ids 1 and 2.

```
    data: [
            {id: 1, name: "Carl", city: "New York"},
            {id: 2, name: "Anna", city: "New York"},
            {id: 3, name: "Carl", city: "Sydney"}
        ]

    filterValue: [1, 2]
```

Comment: Do you want to keep or remove the items in `filterValue`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use `filter` and `indexOf` to filter values in the array using another array

```js
var data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Carl",
    city: "New York"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Anna",
    city: "New York"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Carl",
    city: "Sydney"
  }
]

var filterValue = ["Carl"];
console.log(data.filter(function(e) {
  return filterValue.indexOf(e.name) != -1
}))
```

Comment: is the same solution valid in the name field? @ellipsis

Comment: suppose filterValue = ["Carlos"]; and then run.

Comment: It will return an empty array because there is no match. @BilalSiddiqui

Comment: Why are you using a ternary here? There's no need - just return the boolean - the filter takes a boolean return. In your code, e evaluates to true.

Answer (score 1):

Make a hash map out of `data` with `id` as key.

```js
let data = [
        {id: 1, name: "Carl", city: "New York"},
        {id: 2, name: "Anna", city: "New York"},
        {id: 3, name: "Carl", city: "Sydney"}
    ];
let map1 = new Map(data.map(e=>[e.id,e]));
let filterValue = [1, 2];
let output = filterValue.map(e=>map1.get(e));
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter()` with `.includes()` to check whether or not `obj.filterValue` has the current objects `id`, if it doesn't, you can keep the array, if it does, it will remove it from the new array:

```js
const obj = {data:[{id:1,name:"Carl",city:"New York"},{id:2,name:"Anna",city:"New York"},{id:3,name:"Carl",city:"Sydney"}],filterValue:[1,2]};
const res = obj.data.filter(({id}) => !obj.filterValue.includes(id));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this utility function, which takes the array of values to filter and the key of the object to filter by:

```js
const data = [{ id: 1, name: 'Carl', city: 'New York' }, { id: 2, name: 'Anna', city: 'New York' }, { id: 3, name: 'Carl', city: 'Sydney' }]

const filterData = (d, f, k) => data.filter(o => f.includes(o[k]))

console.log(filterData(data, [1, 2], 'id'))
console.log(filterData(data, ['Carl'], 'name'))
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use .filter() on Array:

```
var data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Carl",
    city: "New York"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Anna",
    city: "New York"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Carl",
    city: "Sydney"
  }
]

var filteredData = data.filter(function(data) {     
    return data.id == 1 || data.id == 2;
})
```

Comment: What if I need id 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,22,33,44,55,667,88? Are you going to write an or condition for all of them?

Comment: This answer is very specific to the question, although we can utilize an array for mentioned requirement.

Comment: OP wants for names too